# Chrome extension: use Background to get data from api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have in my content:

```
test = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ title: "getMyData" }, (res) => {
    console.log({res});
});
console.log({test});
```

background:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (request.hasOwnProperty("title")) {
            switch (request.title) {
                case "getMyData": {
                    sendResponse({test:"test value"});
                    return true;
                }
            }         
        } 
    }
```

I want to send send a message from my content and get some datas through fetch().

With that code I only get undefined.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` doesn't return a Promise. You have to include the logic in your callback function or use [the 'promisifying' polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in two ways:

**Method-1**: In the background case "getMyData", call a separate function to fetch the API data, and then try "*chrome.runtime.sendMessage*" back to the content script to receive the response using same "*chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener*" method. This will be a cleaner and modular way.

**Method-2**: Directly calling the *fetch()* within "*chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener*", retrieve the response and update it back to the content script like below:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.hasOwnProperty("title")) {
    switch (request.title) {
      case "getMyData": {
        var url = request.url; //Your API endpoint
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(response => sendResponse(response))
          .catch()
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```